# How can I increase the space after a \crule in a booktabs table?

Tags: tables, booktabs, height

In the table created in the MWE below, I want the space between the crule and the third row to be slightly greater and the space between the text in the 2nd row and the crule to be slightly smaller. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{table}[tp]
\caption{Minimum Working Example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Dimension} \\
 & & 1st D Value 1  & 1st D Value 2      \\ \cline{3-4} 
 \multirow{2}*{Second dimension} & 2nd D Value1 & Outcome(1,1)  & Outcome(1,2) \\
 & 2nd D Value2 & Outcome(2,1) & Outcome(2,2)       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `\crule`, you mean `\cline` or `\cmidrule`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There is `\cline` in the MWE

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yes, but the OP asks for `\crule` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I think it's a lapsus :)

Comment: Apologies, I should have written \cline rather than \crule. And \cmidrule does look better. Is there a way for me to control explicitly the spacing for \cline or \cmidrule?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: We never cause a lapsus, do we? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course! :):):)

Answer (score 7):

There is no `\crule` macro in `booktabs`, but `\cmidrule`, having the same meaning as `\cline`, but providing more space.

If the regular spacing (controlled by `\aboverulesep` and `\bottomrulesep`) is not sufficient, an explicit `\addlinespace` can be injected:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newlength{\ridiculouslylargecmidrulesep}
\setlength{\ridiculouslylargecmidrulesep}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{table}[tp]
\caption{Minimum Working Example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Dimension} \\
 & & 1st D Value 1  & 1st D Value 2      \\ \cmidrule{3-4} 
 \multirow{2}*{Second dimension} & 2nd D Value1 & Outcome(1,1)  & Outcome(1,2) \\
 & 2nd D Value2 & Outcome(2,1) & Outcome(2,2)       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[tp]
\caption{Minimum Working Example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Dimension} \\
 & & 1st D Value 1  & 1st D Value 2      \\ \addlinespace[\ridiculouslylargecmidrulesep]
\cmidrule{3-4}  \addlinespace[\ridiculouslylargecmidrulesep]
 \multirow{2}*{Second dimension} & 2nd D Value1 & Outcome(1,1)  & Outcome(1,2) \\ 
 & 2nd D Value2 & Outcome(2,1) & Outcome(2,2)       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think that your table may be the rare case that looks better if one employs `\hline` and `\cline`, along with suitably placed vertical lines, than if one uses the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}

\caption{Minimum Working Example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{First Dimension} \\
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 1st D Value 1  & 1st D Value 2  \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Second dimension} & 2nd D Value1 & Outcome(1,1)  & Outcome(1,2) \\
\cline{2-4}
 & 2nd D Value2 & Outcome(2,1) & Outcome(2,2)       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The wrath of a certain Italian mathematician will come over you, for your vertical line blasphemy ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I'll keep my fingers crossed that this certain Italian mathematician is aware of the following paraphrase of a well-known proverb: "There is no `\crule` without an exception". (Groan. Ouch!)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, this is great—much appreciated.